# Convert date and time fields to timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, timestamp

I am working with a SQL Server table that shows `date modified` and `time modified` in two separate columns. I need to combine the two fields into a `timestamp` format, so that I can get a `max` date for future reloads (not having to load the entire database each day).

The issue is that the time is not displayed in normal `hh:mm:ss` format - it is a number `(e.g. 3591859)`. I have added a screenshot of the field, type, etc. (for what it is worth).

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Not entirely sure. It is a Sage database. The link to the table fields can be found here [link](http://sageaom.kcsvar.com/AOM54/GLAMF.HTM)

Comment: what is the database type? MySQL, SQL server or what?

Comment: It is SQL server. I figured out that the number mentioned in the question is actually a time without the ':'. 03:59:18.1900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems an `epoch` time.

```
select  concat(AUDTDATE, ' ', cast(dateadd(second, AUDTTIME,'00:00:00') as time))
```